Install Debian 12 alongside Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11
I have a laptop with a succesfully installed Windows11 and Ubuntu 22.04.
I have 2 nvme ssd disks.
I can start Windows11 or Ubuntu 22.04 via dual boot.
On my first nvme disk (named nvme0n1) have the following partions:

/dev/nvme01n1p1  EFI system partition                fat32 /boot/efi
/dev/nvme01n1p2  Microsoft reserved partition
/dev/nvme01n1p3  Basic Data partition (Windows11 OS) ntfs
/dev/nvme01n1p4  data partion for Windows11          ntfs
/dev/nvme01n1p5  Linux root for Ubuntu 22.04         ext4
/dev/nvme01n1p6  Linux home for Ubuntu 22.04         ext4

My second nvme disk disk (named nvme1n1) has only a Microsoft reserved partition of 15.98 MiB.
Now I want to install Debian12 on my second nvme ssd.
How can I install Debian12, so I can boot Debian12 and still boot Windows11 or Ubuntu 22.04?
I read that I should create a own efi partition my second nvme disk, for debian12.
But how can I achieve this?

If you have ubuntu and windows, why do you need another debian install? You could/should just run it as a VM or container ?

I want to work with it for a while. If I really like it then I will switch permanently to debian.

Install Debian 12 and make sure in the paritioning section of the install to tell it to use /dev/nvme01n1p1 as an EFI partition and a new partition on /dev/nvme1n1 as root partition (/). If you have a swap partition for Ubuntu you can probably also use it for Debian. If all goes well the Grub installation should detect the other operating systems. Not without risk. You should probably make a backup copy of /boot/efi first.

What should do when windows and Ubuntu already is installed on my laptop, to install debian12 which can multi boot?
